# PostgreSQL - Slice the bottom N results and move them to the top

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Let's say, for example, I have a list of email addresses retrieved like so:

```
SELECT email FROM users ORDER BY email
```

This returns:

```
a@email.com
b@email.com
c@email.com
...
x@email.com
y@email.com
z@email.com
```

I'd like to take this result set, slice the bottom 3 emails and move them to the top, so you'd see a result set like:

```
x@email.com
y@email.com
z@email.com -- Note x-z is here
a@email.com
b@email.com
c@email.com
...
u@email.com
v@email.com
w@email.com
```

Is there a way to do this within the SQL? I'd like to not have to do it application-side for memory reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the values are "x" or greater, you can simply do:

```
order by (case when email >= 'x@email.com' then 1 else 2 end),
         email
```

Otherwise, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select email
from (select email, row_number() over (order by email desc) as seqnum
      from users u
     ) u
order by (case when seqnum <= 3 then 1 else 2 end),
         email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one version with window functions `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
SELECT email
  FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY email), count(*) OVER (), email
      FROM users
  ) sq1
  ORDER BY count - 3 >= row_number, email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `email` is defined `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. Else you need to do more.

```
SELECT email
FROM  (SELECT email, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY email DESC) AS rn FROM users) sub
ORDER  BY (rn > 3), rn DESC;
```

In Postgres you can just sort by a `boolean` expression. `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`. More:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

Secondary, sort by the computed row number (`rn`) in descending order. Don't sort by the (more expensive) text column `email` another time. Shorter and simpler - test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, it should be faster, too.