# Row number from one column, but then re-order using another column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.3

I'm aggregating (summing) some data from a purchases table, aggregated by total amount per region.

Data looks something like the following:

```
| id | region | purchase_amount |
| 1  | A      | 30              |
| 2  | A      | 35              |
| 3  | B      | 41              |
```

The aggregated data then looks like this, ordered by total_purchases:

```
| region  | total_purchases |
|   B     |  1238           |
|   A     |  910            |
|   D     |  647            |
|   C     |  512            |
```

I'd like to get a ranking for each region, ordered by total_purchases. I can do this using row_number (using SQLAlchemy at the moment) and this results in a table looking like:

```
| rank | region  | total_purchases |
|  1   |   B     |  1238           |
|  2   |   A     |  910            |
|  3   |   D     |  647            |
|  4   |   C     |  512            |
```

However, there's one more column that I'd like to group by and that's:
 **I want region 'C' to always be the first row, but keep it's ranking.**

This would ideally result in a table looking like:

```
| rank | region  | total_purchases |
|  4   |   C     |  512            |
|  1   |   B     |  1238           |
|  2   |   A     |  910            |
|  3   |   D     |  647            |
```

I can do one or the other, but I can't seem to combine these 2 features together. If I use a `row_number()` function, I get the proper ordering.

I can bring the region 'C' row always to the top using an ordering across 2 columns:

```
ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN region = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 DESC,
     total_purchases DESC
```

However, I can't seem to combine these 2 requirements into the same query.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Updated the tags, using Postgres 9.3

Comment: . . My answer should work in Postgres.  However, if you want valid syntax, you should edit your question and show your query.

Answer (score 2):

USE CTE to achieve that, put your ROW_NUMBER in your main query

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total_purchases DESC) AS Rn
           ,region
           ,total_purchases
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT *
FROM C
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN region = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
         ,total_purchases DESC
```

Comment: I tried this on the original table, but I had to add in the aggregation:
       
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total_purchases DESC) AS Rn
           ,region
           ,SUM(purchases) AS total_purchases
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY region
)       
but it said that the total_purchases row did not exist yet. How would I get around this?

Comment: Instead of `ORDER BY total_purchases` put `ORDER BY SUM(purchases)`

Comment: Ok got it, that works. Now to integrate it into our existing SQLAlchemy code.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
select row_number() over (order by total_purchases desc) as rank,
       region, total_purchases
from table t
order by (case when region = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) desc, total_purchases desc;
```

Comment: That works fine. Now to integrate it into our existing SQLAlchemy queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is about Postgres, we have a proper [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) type and can sort by any boolean expression directly:

```sql
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(purchase_amount) DESC NULLS LAST) AS rank
     , region
     , sum(purchase_amount) AS total_purchases
FROM   purchases 
GROUP  BY region
ORDER  BY (region <> 'C'), 1, region;  -- region as tiebreaker
```

#### Explain

- Window functions are executed *after* aggregate functions, so we don't need a subquery or CTE here.

  - [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)
- `NULLS LAST`?

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- The final `1` is referencing the ordinal position 1 in the `SELECT` list, so we don't have to repeat the expression.
- `ORDER BY (region <> 'C')` ?

  - [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- The [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) seems adequate. As opposed to `row_number()`, equal `total_purchases` rank the same. To break possible ties and get a *stable* result in such cases, add `region` (or whatever) as last item to `ORDER BY`.
  If you use `row_number()` and only `ORDER BY sum(purchase_amount)`, equal totals can switch places in two separate calls. You could add another item to the `ORDER BY` clause of `row_number()` for a similar result, but an equal `rank` is more appropriate for equal `total_purchases` I'd say.