# Join on id or null and get first result

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, lateral

I have created the query below:

```
select * from store str
 left join(
  select * from schedule sdl 
  where day = 3  
  order by
   case when sdl.store_id is null then (
    case when sdl.strong is true then 0 else 2 end
   ) else 1 end, sdl.schedule_id desc
 ) ovr on (ovr.store_id = str.store_id OR ovr.store_id IS NULL)
```

**Sample data:**

```
STORE
[store_id] [title]  
 20010      Shoes-Shop
 20330      Candy-Shop

[SCHEDULE]
[schedule_id] [store_id] [day] [strong] [some_other_data]
 1             20330      3     f        10% Discount
 2             NULL       3     t        0% Discount
```

What I want to get from the `LEFT JOIN` is either data for NULL store_id (global schedule entry - affects all store entries) OR the actual data for the given store_id.

Joining the query like this, returns results with the correct order, but for both NULL and store_id matches. It makes sense using the OR statement on join clause.

**Expected results:**

```
[store_id] [title]     [some_other_data]
 20010      Shoes-Shop  0% Discount
 20330      Candy-Shop  0% Discount
```

**Current Results:**

```
[store_id] [title]     [some_other_data]
 20010      Shoes-Shop  0% Discount
 20330      Candy-Shop  0% Discount
 20330      Candy-Shop  10% Discount
```

If there is a more elegant approach on the subject I would be glad to follow it.

Comment: Thetable definition (`\d tbl` in psql ) and your version of Postgres are core pieces of information for a question like this. And demo data that actually show cases what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` should work just fine, as soon as you get `ORDER BY` right. Basically, matches with `strong = TRUE` in `schedule` have priority, then matches with `store_id IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (st.store_id)
       st.store_id, st.title, sl.some_other_data
FROM   store          st
LEFT   JOIN  schedule sl ON sl.day = 3
                       AND (sl.store_id = st.store_id OR sl.store_id IS NULL)
ORDER  BY NOT strong, store_id IS NULL;
```

This works because:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

Basics for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Alternative with a `LATERAL` join (Postgres 9.3+):

```
SELECT *
FROM   store st
LEFT   JOIN  LATERAL (
   SELECT some_other_data
   FROM   schedule
   WHERE  day = 3
   AND   (store_id = st.store_id OR store_id IS NULL)
   ORDER  BY NOT strong
        , store_id IS NULL
   LIMIT  1
   ) sl ON true;
```

About `LATERAL` joins:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Thank you Erwin. Join Lateral is what I am looking for. Does 9.2.7 support lateral joins ?

Comment: @mallix: Nope. I added a link.

Comment: Distinct on does the trick but messes with my ordering. The query I posted here is a tiny part of the actual query so I will go for the upgrade and the join lateral.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use `distinct on`.  The question is then how you order it:

```
select distinct on (str.store_id) *
from store str left join
     schedule sdl 
     on (sdl.store_id = str.store_id or sdl.store_id is null) and dl.day = 3  
order by str.store_id,
         (case when sdl.store_id is null then 2 else 1 end)
```

This will return the `store` record if available, otherwise the `schedule` record that has a value of `NULL`.  Note:  your query has this notion of `strength`, but the question doesn't explain how to use it.  This can be readily modified to include multiple levels of priorities.

Comment: Distinct on doesn t help. Let me explain. I have a set of stores with fixed discounts. Each store might have overrides set (schedule). Overrides have 3 priority levels: Global override strong (store_id NULL, strong TRUE), Normal Store override (store_id), Global override weak (store_id NULL, strong false) . So the same store might fall in to global and normal. If weak I choose normal, if strong I choose global. But my current query returns 3 records instead of 2. If I limit 1, I lose the global feature for the rest of the stores.

Comment: @mallix . . . `distinct on` should return one value per store, based on the prioritization set up in the `order by`.  This seems like what you want to do.