# PostgreSQL: Grouping then filtering table, with condition for nonexistence

Tags: postgresql, group-by, subquery, window-functions, distinct-on

In PostgreSQL, I have a table that, abstractly, looks like this:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ x ║ 0 ║ y ║ 0 ║
║ x ║ 0 ║ x ║ 1 ║
║ x ║ 1 ║ y ║ 0 ║
║ x ║ 1 ║ z ║ 1 ║
║ y ║ 0 ║ z ║ 0 ║
║ y ║ 0 ║ x ║ 0 ║
║ y ║ 1 ║ y ║ 0 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

I want to transform it in a query into this:

```
╔═══╦═══╦══════╗
║ A ║ B ║  D   ║
╠═══╬═══╬══════╣
║ x ║ 0 ║ 1    ║
║ x ║ 1 ║ null ║
║ y ║ 0 ║ null ║
║ y ║ 1 ║ 0    ║
╚═══╩═══╩══════╝
```

…such that:

1. The input table’s rows are grouped by A and B, and
2. For each A and B pair:

   - If the input table has any row such that A = C, then the output table has a row (A, B, D), where D is from the same row in which A = C.

     For instance, the input table has a row (x, 0, x, 1), in which both A and C are x. That means the output table has a row (x, 0, 1), because D is 1. The (x, 0, y, 0) row (because it also has A = x and B = 0) is discarded.
   - Otherwise, if no such row exists, then the output table has a row (A, B, null).

     For instance, the input table has two rows in which A = y and B = 0—they are (y, 0, z, 0) and (y, 0, x, 0). In neither of these rows does A = C. That means that the output table has a (y, 0, null) row.

I can’t figure out any way to use [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), or [subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html) to perform this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a single row from each group with the same `(A, B)` there is a simple, short and fast way: **[`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)** -  not involving aggregate functions, window functions, or subqueries at all:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A, B)
       A, B, CASE WHEN A = C THEN D END AS D
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY A, B, (A = C) DESC;
```

Produces your desired result exactly.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92d1c732a05787ef56eae249442a952b)*

Assuming all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`, or you need to do more.

The final `ORDER BY` item `(A = C) DESC` sorts the row with `A = C` first per group. It's a `boolean` expression, and `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`. If there can be multiple rows, add more `ORDER BY` items to break ties.

`CASE WHEN A = C THEN D END` implements your requirement that `D` is only output for the given condition. Else we get `NULL` (the default for [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)), as desired.

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

More performance optimization may be possible for big tables:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE which returns all the rows where `A = C` and join to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select * from tablename
  where "A" = "C"
)  
select distinct t."A", t."B", c."D"
from tablename t left join cte c
on c."A" = t."A" and c."B" = t."B"
order by t."A", t."B"
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhTCy6oE9fdys2Mg31WHor/0).
Results:

```
| A   | B   | D   |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x   | 0   | 1   |
| x   | 1   |     |
| y   | 0   |     |
| y   | 1   | 0   |
```