# Unexpected effect of filtering on result from crosstab() query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, crosstab

I have a `crosstab()` query like the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
 'SELECT row_name, extra1, extra2..., another_table.category, value
  FROM   table t
  JOIN   another_table ON t.field_id = another_table.field_id
  WHERE  t.field = certain_value AND t.extra1 = val1
  ORDER  BY row_name ASC',
 'SELECT category_name FROM category_name WHERE field = certain_value'
) AS ct(row_name text, extra1 text, extra2 text, ...)
```

Simplified example, the actual query is really complex and contains important information. The above query returns *N* result rows after filtering with `table.extra1 = val1`.

When I change the query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
 'SELECT row_name, extra1, extra2..., another_table.category, value
  FROM   table t
  JOIN   another_table ON t.field_id = another_table.field_id
  WHERE  t.field = certain_value AND t.extra1 IN (val1, ...) --> more values
  ORDER  BY row_name ASC',
 'SELECT category_name FROM category_name WHERE field = certain_value'
) AS ct(row_name text, extra1 text, extra2 text, ...)
WHERE extra1 = val1; --> condition on the result
```

Added more possible values `table.extra1 IN (val1, ...)` and a final condition `WHERE extra1 = val1`. Now I get *fewer* rows than from the original one. To make it worse, if I add yet more values to `IN (val1, ...)`, I get yet *fewer* rows. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extra1, extra2,  ...` are **"extra columns"** in crosstab terminology.
[The manual for the tablefunc module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) explains the rules:

> It may also have one or more “extra” columns. The `row_name` column must
>   be first. The category and `value` columns must be the last two columns,
>   in that order. Any columns between `row_name` and `category` are treated
>   as “extra”. **The “extra” columns are expected to be the same for all rows with the same `row_name` value.**

And further down:

> The output `row_name` column, plus any “extra” columns, are **copied from the first row of the group**.

Bold emphasis on key parts by me.

You only sort by `row_name`:

```
ORDER  BY row_name ASC
```

Does not matter in the first example where you filter with:

```
WHERE ... t.extra1 = 'val1'  -- single quotes by me
```

All input row have `extra1 = 'val1'` anyway. But it matters in the second example where you filter with:

```
WHERE ... t.extra1 IN('val1', ...) --> More values
```

Now, the first bolded requirement above is violated for the extra column `extra1`. While the sort order of the first input query is non-deterministic, resulting values for the "extra" column `extra1` are picked arbitrarily. The more possible values for `extra1`, the fewer rows will end up having 'val1': that's what you observed.

You can still make it work: to report `extra1 = 'val1'` for every `row_name` that has at least one of those, change the `ORDER BY` to:

```
ORDER  BY row_name, (extra1 <> 'val1')
```

Sorts 'val1' on top. Explanation for that `boolean` expression (with links to more):

- [PostgreSQL: Grouping then filtering table, with condition for nonexistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184462/postgresql-grouping-then-filtering-table-with-condition-for-nonexistence/57187868#57187868)

Other "extra" columns are still chosen arbitrarily while the sort order is not deterministic.

Crosstab basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
- [Postgresql crosstab query with multiple "row name" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312739/postgresql-crosstab-query-with-multiple-row-name-columns/43313667#43313667)

Comment: I still have some problems with multiple values. For example, if I filter `extra1` with `val2`, I get 100 results. However, if I use `...t.extra1 IN('val1', 'val2')` and `...(extra1 <> 'val1'), (extra1 <> 'val2')`, I get different result sizes for those which have extra1 with 'val2', around `80`

Comment: You would `ORDER BY row_name, (extra1 <> 'val2')` in this case to get 'val2' wherever available. (Drop `(extra1 <> 'val1')` from the list.)

Comment: The problem is that `extra1` can have one value from a list `['value1', 'value2', 'value3'...'valueN']` of permitted values. The normal case is to permit filtering with multiple values `['value1', 'value2']` and not just one. Is still possible to achieve it with `<>` operator?

Comment: Please ask a new question with all necessary details. Comments are not the place ... (You can always link to this one for context, and drop a link back in the comments here to get my attention.)

Comment: You are right :). Here appears a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221777/unexpected-effect-of-filtering-on-result-from-crosstab-query-with-multiple-val