# How to order SQL queries with conditionals?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I need help with it.

I have a table with the next data

```
|---id---|-----name-----|--value--|
|    1   |     Alex     |   300   |
|    2   |     John     |   800   |
|    3   |     Mary     |   0     |
|    4   |     Carl     |   100   |
|    5   |     Jesus    |   0     |
|    6   |     Aron     |   0     |
```

To order the table by `value`, I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER_BY value DESC;
```

But sometimes I get a result like:

```
|---id---|-----name-----|--value--|
|    2   |     John     |   800   |
|    1   |     Alex     |   300   |
|    4   |     Carl     |   100   |
|    5   |     Jesus    |   0     |
|    3   |     Mary     |   0     |  -- !
|    6   |     Aron     |   0     |
```

I want to order the table with a condition: *"if value is not 0 order by value and if value is 0 order by id"* to get:

```
|---id---|-----name-----|--value--|
|    2   |     John     |   800   |
|    1   |     Alex     |   300   |
|    4   |     Carl     |   100   |
|    3   |     Mary     |   0     |
|    5   |     Jesus    |   0     |
|    6   |     Aron     |   0     |
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no negative values (as shown in your sample data), then adding another sort criteria on `id` is sufficient:

```
order by value desc, id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can order by BOOLEAN

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY (VALUE<>0)::BOOL DESC, value DESC, ID ASC
```

this will give what you need

...and playing with all three directions you can get reorder as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE VALUE<>0
ORDER_BY value DESC,ID
```

It's up to you if add `DESC` at the end to order the ID descencing.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the question says that values can't be negative, or `NULL`. To not depend on `0` sorting last:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY value = 0, value DESC NULLS LAST, id;
```

This also sorts possible `NULL` values last. Those would sort first in `DESCENDING` order. (You did not specify what to do with those, if any.)

See:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)