# Replace NULL values per partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, window-functions, coalesce

I want to fill `NULL` values in `device` column for each `session_id` with an associated non-NULL value. How can I achieve that?

**Here is the sample data:**

```
+------------+-------+---------+
| session_id | step  | device  |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 351acc     | step1 |         |
| 351acc     | step2 |         |
| 351acc     | step3 | mobile  |
| 351acc     | step4 | mobile  |
| 350bca     | step1 | desktop |
| 350bca     | step2 |         |
| 350bca     | step3 |         |
| 350bca     | step4 | desktop |
+------------+-------+---------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+------------+-------+---------+
| session_id | step  | device  |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 351acc     | step1 | mobile  |
| 351acc     | step2 | mobile  |
| 351acc     | step3 | mobile  |
| 351acc     | step4 | mobile  |
| 350bca     | step1 | desktop |
| 350bca     | step2 | desktop |
| 350bca     | step3 | desktop |
| 350bca     | step4 | desktop |
+------------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [window function **`first_value()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) with the right ordering is probably cheapest:

```sql
SELECT session_id, step
     , COALESCE(device
              , first_value(device) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY device IS NULL, step)
               ) AS device
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY session_id DESC, step;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6dfac859e44b847c5d0e76a37e2354e8)*

`ORDER BY device IS NULL, step` sorts `NULL` values last, so the earliest `step` with a notnull value is picked. See:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

If notnull devices per `session_id` are always the same, you can simplify to just `ORDER BY device IS NULL`. And you don't need `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 2):

According to your data sample, there is one device per session, so you could just add a subquery to get the value from the other rows

```
WITH j (session_id, step, device) AS (
  VALUES ('351acc','step1',NULL),
         ('351acc','step2',NULL),
         ('351acc','step3','mobile'),
         ('351acc','step4','mobile'),
         ('350bca','step1','desktop'),
         ('350bca','step2',NULL),
         ('350bca','step3',NULL),
         ('350bca','step4','desktop')
) 
SELECT session_id,step,
  (SELECT DISTINCT device 
   FROM j q2
   WHERE q2.session_id = q1.session_id AND q2.device IS NOT NULL) AS device
FROM j q1 ORDER BY session_id,step;

 session_id | step  | device  
------------+-------+---------
 350bca     | step1 | desktop
 350bca     | step2 | desktop
 350bca     | step3 | desktop
 350bca     | step4 | desktop
 351acc     | step1 | mobile
 351acc     | step2 | mobile
 351acc     | step3 | mobile
 351acc     | step4 | mobile
(8 Zeilen)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fe46c3db41a370d110454ab27ad135ef)

Answer (score 1):

```
select session_id, step,coalesce(device, max(device) over (partition by session_id order by step desc)) device
from table
```