# Postgresql "Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" when using CASE expression inside ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I get the `column "measurementResults.value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error for this query:

```
SELECT avg("measurementResults"."value") AS "value",
       min("measurement"."timestamp") AS "timestamp",
       min("testProtocolItemResults"."ranking") AS "ranking"
FROM "measurement"
JOIN "measurementResults" ON "measurementResults"."measurement" = "measurement"."id"
JOIN "conditions" ON "conditions"."measurement" = "measurement"."id"
JOIN "testProtocolItemResults" ON "testProtocolItemResults"."id" = "measurementResults"."testProtocolItemResults"
JOIN "testProtocolSessionItem" ON "testProtocolSessionItem"."id" = "measurement"."testProtocolSessionItem"
WHERE "measurement"."athlete" = 334
  AND "measurementResults"."testProtocolItemResults" = 1
  AND "conditions"."conditions" = '6'
GROUP BY "testProtocolSessionItem"."testProtocolSession",
         "testProtocolItemResults"."ranking"
ORDER BY (CASE
              WHEN "ranking" = 'greater'::text THEN "value"
              ELSE NULL::double precision
          END) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

If I change the ORDER BY clause like this, it works as expected:

```
...
ORDER BY "value" DESC
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make it a habit to declare your Postgres version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has a couple of roots:

Most importantly, don't use the **same name** for an output column that is distinct from an input column (of the same name). That's a loaded foot-gun.

Secondly, make it a habit to table-qualify **all** columns used in a complex query involving multiple tables. Even if that seems to work, it might already be doing something else than you think. And even if it works correctly it may break later, if any column names are changed (added, removed renamed). With some bad luck it breaks silently, and your query happily ever after produces nonsense.

Thirdly, the SQL standard, which has somewhat confusing visibility rules. See:

- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

In your working alternative query, `"value"` resolves to the **output** column `"value"`, which hides any input column of the same name in `ORDER BY`. That works as expected (that is, if you actually meant to target the output column).

In your failing query, `"value"` resolves to the **input** column `"measurementResults.value"`. You cannot throw output columns into a new computation in `ORDER BY`, you can only use them "as is". So, with output columns out of the way, `"value"` resolves to the input column (now not hidden any more). And that leads to the reported error. Obviously, you cannot order by an input column after aggregating - except if you grouped by it, directly or indirectly.

You could repair your query with:

```
ORDER  BY (ranking = 'greater') IS TRUE, "value" DESC
```

The sorts all rows where `ranking = 'greater'` is not true to the top - like your `CASE` expression would. So treating `null` and `false` alike.

Subtle difference: Those leading rows are sorted by `value`, while your original would list them in arbitrary order. May or may not be welcome.

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

I assume you are aware that `null` values sort on top in descending order? And that you can change that?  See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

If that's not good enough (or for more complex expressions), you must be more verbose and explicit: one way is to wrap the whole query into a subquery, and order (and limit!) in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT avg_value, min_timestamp, min_ranking
FROM  (
   SELECT ir.ranking                          -- !
        , avg(mr."value")    AS avg_value     -- !
        , min(m."timestamp") AS min_timestamp -- !
        , min(ir.ranking)    AS min_ranking   -- !
   FROM   measurement               m
   JOIN   "measurementResults"      mr ON mr.measurement = m.id
   JOIN   conditions                c  ON c.measurement = m.id
   JOIN   "testProtocolItemResults" ir ON ir.id = mr."testProtocolItemResults"
   JOIN   "testProtocolSessionItem" si ON si.id = m."testProtocolSessionItem"
   WHERE  m."athlete" = 334
   AND    mr."testProtocolItemResults" = 1
   AND    c."conditions" = '6'
   GROUP  BY si."testProtocolSession", ir.ranking
   ) sub
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN ranking = 'greater' THEN "value" END DESC
LIMIT  3
```

Especially for queries with a small `LIMIT`, this may be more expensive if Postgres cannot optimize the query plan as well any more.

Aside:
Use [legal, loser-case identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860), so you don't have to double-quote.
And use [table aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) to de-noise your big queries.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. In my case, I have five CASE expressions in the ORDER BY clause. Is the subquery only solution in this case or is there another solution as well?